# Setting up indexes for multiple foreign keys

Tags: sql, indexing, foreign-keys

An error message regarding indexes displays when foreign keys are added using the following scripts. I have added primary keys and indexes different ways but not sure if the diagram is providing information about how to setup the indexes/primary keys that I'm not seeing.

```
CREATE TABLE aocommercial_building(
parcel CHAR(25) NOT NULL,
suffix INT NOT NULL,
owner VARCHAR(255) NULL,
owner2 VARCHAR(255) NULL,
);

CREATE TABLE aocommercial_heatcool(
parcel CHAR(25) NOT NULL,
suffix INT NOT NULL,
section INT NULL,
heat_cool_cd VARCHAR(255) NULL
);

CREATE TABLE aocommercial_unit(
parcel CHAR(25) NOT NULL,
suffix INT NOT NULL,
section INT NOT NULL,
occ_desc VARCHAR(255) NULL
);

CREATE TABLE aocom_misc_bldg(
parcel CHAR(25) NOT NULL,
suffix INT NOT NULL,
section INT NOT NULL,
misc_bldg_type VARCHAR(255) NULL
);

ALTER TABLE aocommercial_unit ADD FOREIGN KEY (parcel) REFERENCES aocommercial_building(parcel);
ALTER TABLE aocommercial_unit ADD FOREIGN KEY (suffix) REFERENCES aocommercial_building(suffix);
ALTER TABLE aocommercial_heatcool ADD FOREIGN KEY (parcel) REFERENCES aocommercial_unit(parcel);
ALTER TABLE aocommercial_heatcool ADD FOREIGN KEY (suffix) REFERENCES aocommercial_unit(suffix);
ALTER TABLE aocommercial_heatcool ADD FOREIGN KEY (section) REFERENCES aocommercial_unit(section);
ALTER TABLE aocom_misc_bldg ADD FOREIGN KEY (parcel) REFERENCES aocommercial_unit(parcel);
ALTER TABLE aocom_misc_bldg ADD FOREIGN KEY (suffix) REFERENCES aocommercial_unit(suffix);
ALTER TABLE aocom_misc_bldg ADD FOREIGN KEY (section) REFERENCES aocommercial_unit(section);
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u0Lhq.png)

Comment: A foreign key constraint references a key, but your tables have no keys. And it's highly unlikely that your table `aocommercial_building` is the parcel table with one row per parcel (key = parcel) and the suffix table with one row per suffix (key = suffix) at the same time. *Maybe* it is the parcel-suffix table with one row per parcel and suffix, in which case you would create a primary key on the two columns and reference them both in foreign keys, e.g. `ALTER TABLE aocommercial_unit ADD FOREIGN KEY (parcel, suffix) REFERENCES aocommercial_building(parcel, suffix);`

Comment: Unrelated, but: you almost certainly do **not** want to use `char(n)` - use `varchar(n)` instead

Comment: Hi Thorsten the example you provided narrowed down I am creating primary keys incorrectly.  Thanks.  I'm not sure if the diagram I posted as "image description" was helpful but it looks like you got it

Answer (score 0):

For each table, what column (or combination of columns) uniquely identifies each row?  Then, include in each `CREATE TABLE` another line with `PRIMARY KEY(...)`.

For each table, if there is no particular set of columns to uniquely define each row, then add

```
id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
PRIMARY KEY(id)
```

Look around; there are lots and lots of examples.